# C# Parse text file

Tags: c#, json, linq, parsing

I am trying to parse a file in MVC C#, see the format below.   Since its not in JSON I cannot use the Javascript serializer to deserialize to an object.  The other option is use to LINQ and read line by line and retrieve the desired values.  Could any one recommend a more efficient way to do it.

The first field I need to retrieve is the ASSAY NUMBER (for example value 877) from ASSAYS
and then the ASSAY_STATUS field from TEST_REPLICATE which could be multiple nodes. Thanks

```
LOAD_HEADER
{
    EXPERIMENT_FILE_NAME      "xyz.json"
    EXPERIMENT_START_DATE_TIME  05.21.2012 03:44:01
    OPERATOR_ID     "Q_SI"
}
ASSAYS
{
    ASSAY_NUMBER            877
    ASSAY_VERSION           4
    ASSAY_CALIBRATION_VERSION   1
}

TEST_REPLICATE
{
    REPLICATE_ID            1985
    ASSAY_NUMBER            877
    ASSAY_VERSION           4
    ASSAY_STATUS            Research
}
TEST_REPLICATE
{
    REPLICATE_ID            1985
    ASSAY_NUMBER            877
    ASSAY_VERSION           4
    ASSAY_STATUS            Research
}
```

Comment: The best solution would be to use or write parser for this DSL.  But if it's simple enough (and assuming the strings in quotes cannot contain escape characters or curly braces) you could probably get by with some crude string manipulation.

Comment: `Could any one recommend a more efficient way to do it` Show your inefficient version so that I can think of a more efficient one. Or should i interprete it `write the code for me` ?

Comment: yes, if you have a code solution please share

Answer (score 0):

You could either hack something together or use a parser generator like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) or [Coco/R](http://www.ssw.uni-linz.ac.at/coco/). Both can generate parsers in C#.

Answer (score 0):

I'm more fond of using a parser-combinator (a tool for constructing parsers using parser building blocks) than parser generators. I've had passable experience with [Piglet](https://github.com/dervall/Piglet), which is written with/for C#, and is pretty easy to use, and amazing experience with [FParsec](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/), but it's written for F#.

As far as parser generators go, there are those suggested by stmax, and there is also [TinyPG](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28294/a-Tiny-Parser-Generator-v1-2), which a member recommended me once.

You can also roll your own parser. I suggest basing it on some sort of state machine model, though in this simple case, like Kirk Woll suggested, you could probably get by with some plain old string manipulation.

Comment: Can you give an example please

Comment: example of what? which one? I suggest going for the parser-combinator unless you have a reason for not doing so. I think if you check out piglet, you'll see half the work is already done for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this hinges upon whether or not there will ever be more than one ASSAY_NUMBER value in the file. If so, the easiest and surest way I know is to read the file line-by-line and get the data you desire.

If, however, you know that each file is unique to a specific ASSY_NUMBER, you have a much simpler answer: read the file as one string and use REGEX to pull out the information you desire. I am not an expert on REGEX, but there are enough examples online that you should be able to create one that works.